# Do the magic items from the Layer of Delusion work after they leave that layer?

Tags: magic-items, published-adventures, adnd-2e

I'm running the Bloodstone Lands adventure and the party managed to get to the last adventure. They ended up travelling to the Abyss and once they were on the first layer, they went through the first conduit and ended up in the Layer of Delusion.

In it, it states

> This indeed appears to be Bloodstone Pass, but it is actually the Layer of Delusion, a sentient being seeking to destroy all who enter by simulating a pleasant environment. Its power is such that it can mask itself against the range of normal detect spells, including the innate detect evil ability of paladins. All the NPCs of Bloodstone Pass are present, welcoming the heroes home. Quillan the Sage shows up to tell the heroes that they have evidently found an interplanar conduit that brought them back to Bloodstone, and that they can return to the Abyss soon, "after you've regained your strength and restored your magic." Quillan tells them he has discovered a new source of magic, and gives each of them what seem to be the magical items of their dreams, holy swords +10, rod of infinite spell casting, etc. The items all appear to work while in this layer.

What confuses me is that it specifically says that the items all appear to work while in that layer but it doesn't say that if they leave the layer with the items if they still work or not. When I saw those items I thought that those items were overpowered in a sense and that if they left the layer with them that they shouldn't work but it doesn't say whether or not they do.

Answer (score 2):

## The items are not real because they are a simulation.

The part of the description that is relevant is:

> seeking to destroy all who enter by simulating a pleasant environment.

Similarly, the NPC's and everything else is a simulation.  It's not the actual Bloodstone Pass, nor are the NPCS, items, etc...

[Simulation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/simulation):

> 1. Imitation of a situation or process.
>
>    1.1 The action of pretending; deception.

### Naration

You could make this obvious upon exiting the layer, the items they are holding are mundane or even poor imitations.  Perhaps the swords are bones with pointy ends, staves or rods are columns of fossilized fungus, etc.